# Issue with displaying of information in a Tables/Matrix visual - Power BI

Tags: visualization, powerbi, dax

Hi I'm new to Power BI desktop, but have come across an issue when displaying information, Hopefully it's due to my lack of knowledge, but I can't seem to find a way to display values in rows one after the other similar to Pivot tables functionality.

For example so if I had the following table

```
 Location | Salary | Number

 A        | 100    | 1

 A        | 200    | 2

 B        | 100    | 3

 B        | 400    | 4

 C        | 400    | 5

 D        | 800    | 6
```

What I'd like to produce is something like .....

```
 A   | B   | C   | D
 300 | 500 | 400 | 800    <-- Salary Sum 
 3   | 7   | 5   | 6      <-- Number Sum
```

I have a direct link with my data source, please suggest a way to display the same with tables/matrix

Thank you in advance

Comment: With the August update, this has become possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported in Power BI, but maybe there is some light at the end of the tunnel... The Power BI team have started working on this much requested feature. See [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/10948962-matrix-measures-or-values-on-rows-instead-of-colum)

Answer (score 1):

As Tom said, this is available with the August release. You can check which version you have by going to File -> Help -> About. If you have an older verion, you can go [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45331) to download the right one for you (32-bit vs 64-bit).

[image: About]

Once you have made sure you are running the August version, simply create a matrix with Location in the Columns field and Salary and Number in the Values field. Then go into the formatting pane and under Values, turn Show on rows to on.

[image: Matrix]

[image: Options]

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Go to query editor, select the first column of the desired table, location in your case and from transform tab, select unpivot other columns.
That's it! Now go and drop your visual.